# Can the Dell H730 Raid Adapter be used in none Dell boards?

Tags: motherboard, raid, hardware-raid

I notice that HP, Dell raid cards being sold separately, can these cards be used in boards other than HP and DELL?

Comment: [The RAID Controller in question is a standard x8 PCI Express 3.0 device.](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H730.pdf).  The only thing that would prevent you from using the controller on other hardware would be the Dell software and/or the Dell drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, These cards are perfectly capable of working in any PC based system with the compatible PCI-E 3.0 slot. They are not limited to the specific brand manufacturer. I.E. Dell or HP but you may be limited based on the operating system you are using dependent upon available drivers.